# Python mysql package not running REPLACE statement

Tags: python, mysql, wordpress

I'm having a problem where I have a SQL statement that when run in my MySQL Workbench executes properly, but when run with python's mysql package function `cursor.execute()` doesn't work. The problem SQL statement is:

> REPLACE INTO mmm_dev.samp_wp_links SELECT * FROM mmm_master.samp_wp_links;

The statement is supposed to copy all data from `mmm_master` into `mmm_dev`. The following the python code that I'm using to execute the query:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
def examine(cursor, cnx):
    try:
            qry = cursor.execute("REPLACE INTO mmm_dev.samp_wp_links SELECT * FROM mmm_master.samp_wp_links;")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print("Failed to select everything")
            exit(1)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It fails silently. When I execute the query on my SQL GUI it works, but when I run it through python it fails.

Comment: Where do you call `examine()`?

Comment: I don't call examine, should I be?

Comment: `def` only declares a function but doesn't execute it. You have to execute it somewhere.

Comment: Ah, yes I do, it's above in my `main` that I didn't include.

Comment: Then it can't fail silently. Either it works or raise an exception. Insert debugging prints and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Python libraries are [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)-compliant:

> .commit () Commit any pending transaction to the database.
>
> Note that if the database supports an auto-commit feature, this must
>   be initially off. An interface method may be provided to turn it back
>   on.
>
> Database modules that do not support transactions should implement
>   this method with void functionality.

Call `cnx.commit()`

Answer (score 1):

Call `examine()`. Debug with `print()`:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
def examine(cursor):
    print("[DEBUG] 1: before query")
    try:
            qry = cursor.execute("REPLACE INTO mmm_dev.samp_wp_links SELECT * FROM mmm_master.samp_wp_links;")
            print("[DEBUG] 2: after query")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print("Failed to select everything %s" % err)
            exit(1)
    print("[DEBUG] 3: success")
examine(cursor)
```

Comment: I called examine above in my main.

Comment: it printed all 3 debug statements, but the database remains unupdated

Comment: Hey, Thanks for all your help Cez's answer fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a **commit**.

```
mydb.commit()
```

in order to **save** the changes.